# JQ: accessing element no matter how many levels deep

Tags: json, nested, jq

Given the file `test.json`

```
{
  "file": {
    "id": "123456789",
    "name": "137.txt"
  },
  "lines": 219,
  "characters": 2456
}
```

I would like to access element `name` using JQ from the command line.

Typing `jq .file.name test.json` produces `137.txt`. Perfect!

Unfortunately our real json structure is much bigger and typing the full path of an element can be painful.

Is it possible to retrieve the value of `name` without typing the full path? Something like `jq *.name test.json` with `*` being a wildcard?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One way would be to recurse deep with the `..` to get as deep as possible and *if* the value is present and *not* null as

```
jq '.. | .name? | select(. != null)'
```